# change div on table row click event

Tags: jquery, html

am trying to create table where on clicking each row should change content on the div side to it just like jquery tabs...

the code i used for this is

html

```
<table>
   <tr id="oone">
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="ttwo">
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="tthree">
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<div class="sample">
    <div id="one">
      one
    </div>
    <div id="two">
     two        
    </div>
    <div id="three">
     three      
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
table{
    float:left;
}
table tr td{
   border:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px;
}
.sample{
    width:300px;
    height:145px;
    background-color:#999;
    float:left;
}

#one{
    display: none;
}
.current{
    display:block;
}

#two{
    display: none;
}
#three{
    display: none;
}
```

jquery 1.7.2 on load

```
$(function(){

$("table tr").click(function(){

    event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
});
});
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamshi6699/n3ng3g4q/)

the thing is if i put on the first tr tag its changing in the div then after second tr it should show the second div its not working....

thanks for your time...

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting tab to $(this).attr('href'), when your table row elements don't have href attributes?

Comment: Why are you selecting `tab-content` if it does not even exist!

Comment: So, when the user clicks on the first row, you want the div `#one` to be shown inside `.sample`?

Comment: Plus, event is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3518Ldgk/

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr data-tab="one">
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-tab="two">
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-tab="three">
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<div class="sample">
    <div class="tab-content" id="one">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="two">
     two        
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="three">
     three      
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    float:left;
}
table tr td{
   border:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px;
}
.sample{
    width:300px;
    height:145px;
    float:left;
}

.current{
    background-color: yellow;
}

#one{
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
}

#two{
    display: none;
    background-color: green;
}
#three{
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

$("table td").click(function(){

    event.preventDefault();
        $('table td').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).parent().attr("data-tab");
        $('.tab-content').hide();
        $('#' + tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so if I understand correctly, here's how you can do it by modifying your code a bit:

First, make the HREF attributes you were trying to find:

```
<table>
    <tr href='one'><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr href='two'><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr href='three'><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></td>
</table>

<div class="sample">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
    <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    $($('#' + $(this).attr("href"))).siblings().hide().end().fadeIn();
});
```

Which finds the div with the ID that matches your href attribute, hides its siblings first, then fades it in as requested. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nh6kL12o/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle. I think this simplifies it even more:

http://jsfiddle.net/n3ng3g4q/3/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr id="oone" data-value="one">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ttwo" data-value="two">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tthree" data-value="three">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="sample">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
    <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

    $("tr").click(function () {
        $(".sample div").css({
            "display": "none"
        })
        var val = $(this).data("value");
        $("#" + val).css({
            "display": "block"
        });
    });
});
```